# snakemake - wildcards from python dictionary

Tags: python, snakemake

I am writing a snakemake file that has input files on a specific location, with specific folder names (for this example, `barcode9[456]`). I need to change the naming conventions in these directories so I now want to add a first rule to my snakemake, which would link the folders in the original location (`FASTQ_PATH`) to an output folder in the snakemake working directory. The names of the link folders in this directory come from a python dictionay `d`, defined in the snakemake. I would then use these directories as input for the downstream rules.

So the first rule of my snakemake is actually a python script (`scripts/ln.py`) that maps the naming convention in the original directory to the desired naming conventions, and links the fastqs:

The snakemake looks like so:

```
FASTQ_PATH = '/path/to/original_location'


# dictionary that maps the subdirectories in FASTQ_PATH (keys) with the directory names that I want in the snakemake working directory (values)
d = {'barcode94': 'IBC_UZL-CV5-04',
 'barcode95': 'IBC_UZL-CV5-42',
 'barcode96': 'IBC_UZL-CV5-100'}



rule all:
    input:
        expand('symLinkFq/{barcode}', barcode = list(d.values())) # for each element in list(d.values()) I want to create a subdirectory that would point to the corresponding path in the original location (FASTQ_PATH)



rule symlink:
    input:
        FASTQ_PATH,
        d
    output:
        'symLinkFq/{barcode}'
    script:
        "scripts/ln.py"
```

The python script that I am calling to make the links is shown below

```
import pandas as pd
import subprocess as sp
import os

# parsing variables from Snakefile
d_sampleNames = snakemake.input[1]
fastq_path = snakemake.input[0]


os.makedirs('symLinkFq')
for barcode in list(d_sampleNames.keys()):
    idx = list(d_sampleNames.keys()).index(barcode)
    sampleName = list(d_sampleNames.values())[idx]
    
    sp.run(f"ln -s {fastq_path}/{barcode} symLinkFq/{sampleName}", shell=True) # the relative path with respect to the working directory should suffice for the DEST in the ln -s command
```

But when I call `snakemake -np -s Snakefile` I get

```
Building DAG of jobs...
MissingInputException in line 15 of /nexusb/SC2/ONT/scripts/SnakeMake/minimalExample/renameFq/Snakefile:
Missing input files for rule symlink:
barcode95
barcode94
barcode96
```

The error kind of makes sense to me. The only 'input' files that I have are python variables instead of being files that do exist in my system.

I guess the issue that I am having comes down to the fact that the wildcards that I want to use for all rules are not present in any file that can be used as input, so what I can think of using is the dictionary with the correspondence, though it is not working as I tried.

Does anyone know how to get around this, any other different approach is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I think it could be easier...

I would reverse the key/value mapping (here with `dict(zip(...))`) than use a lambda input function to get the source directory for each output key:

```
FASTQ_PATH = '/path/to/files'

d = {'barcode94': 'IBC_UZL-CV5-04',
 'barcode95': 'IBC_UZL-CV5-42',
 'barcode96': 'IBC_UZL-CV5-100'}

d = dict(zip(d.values(), d.keys())) # Values become keys and viceversa

rule all:
    input:
        expand('symLinkFq/{barcode}', barcode = d.keys()) 

rule symlink:
    input:
        indir= lambda wc: os.path.join(FASTQ_PATH, d[wc.barcode]),
    output:
        outdir= directory('symLinkFq/{barcode}'),
    shell:
        r"""
        ln -s {input.indir} {output.outdir}
        """
```

As an aside, in a python script I would use `os.symlink()` instead of spawning a subprocess and call `ln -s` - I think it's easier to debug if something goes wrong.

Comment: it could be simpler as you suggested yes, I initially wanted to write a rule with shell commands, not a python script but I was struggling with finding the correct notation for the wildcards, quotes, number of curly braces etc. Thanks very much